# How do I perform text search on Cloudkit records?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I have Cloudkit records with a '`Keywords`' field of type '`text`'

I can use this pattern to fetch just the Keywords field of ALL records

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Library", predicate: predicate)
var operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)  
operation.desiredKeys = ["KeyWords"]
operation.recordFetchedBlock = { [weak self] (record:CKRecord!) in
  ...
}
operation.queryCompletionBlock = { [weak self] (cursor:CKQueryCursor!, error:NSError!) in
  ...
}
self.publicDatabase!.addOperation(operation)
```

I'd like to limit the returned records to those where the KeyWords field matches a search string which I assume means providing a suitable predicate.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKQuery_class/index.html) indicates that CONTAINS is only for lists UNLESS you use the self keyword which searches all text fields

However, replacing the predicate declaration with:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchString)
```

results in

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CKException', reason: 'Predicate comparison options are not supported for expression: SELF CONTAINS[c]
```

and using

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS %@", searchString)
```

results in

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CKException', reason: 'Unexpected expression: SELF CONTAINS
```

I am sure it is something straightforward but the docs are not complete yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this predicate for a token search:

```
NSPredicate(format: "allTokens TOKENMATCHES[cdl] %@", tokens)
```

update:
This functionality seems to have changed. You can now use:

```
NSPredicate(format: @"self contains %@", tokens)
```

or this:

```
NSPredicate(format: @"self contains 'bob' AND self contains ‘smith’”)
```

Fro more info see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckquery

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I get a CK error: `'Invalid predicate: userName TOKENMATCHES[cdl] "sc" (Error Domain=CKErrorDomain Code=12 "Invalid operator in <userName TOKENMATCHES[cdl] "sc">: Unsupported operator: TOKENMATCHES`

Comment: Using iOS 13, Swift 5, Xcode 11. This crashes reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "%@"'...